# React Big Calendar using hooks inside onNavigate prevents navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I'm using react-big-calendar to display events, I want to call a function to set state inside the onNavigate callback but doing this prevents navigation to the next month in the calendar view.

This is what I want to do which results to the calendar view not navigating

```
const [calendarStartDate, setCalendarStartDate] = useState(new Date());

        <DraggableCalendar
        localizer={localizer}
        defaultView="month"
        events={scheduledTestCases}
        style={{ height: "80%", width: "95%" }}
        views={{week: true, day: true, month: true}}
        onNavigate={(newDate: Date, view: View)=>setCalendarStartDate(newDate)}
      />
```

currently I can do this inside the onNavigate callback and the navigation works fine

```
    <DraggableCalendar
    localizer={localizer}
    defaultView="month"
    events={scheduledTestCases}
    style={{ height: "80%", width: "95%" }}
    views={{week: true, day: true, month: true}}
    onNavigate={(newDate: Date, view: View)=>console.log(newDate)}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

React-Big-Calendar has three variables that can be '*controlled*' or '*uncontrolled*'. When you provide `onView`, `onNavigate` and `onSelectEvent` methods, RBC expects **you** to control the state of `view`, `date` and `selected` yourself. By providing your own `onNavigate` without a state controlled `date` prop, it will call your method, but most of the internals will do nothing.